# UK Ordnance Survey Code Point. Projection change (OSGB 1936 to WSG84)

Tags: coordinate-system, ordnance-survey

I am trying to overlay CodePoint with Polygons onto leaflet JS. My current problem is converting the .shp file into the correct projection and a kml.

If I open the shp file (using qgis) with the projection of "OSGB 1636" which (from what I understand is the correct projection), when I "Save as" and select the new projection of "WSG84". This is the result:

```
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
  <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf inf,inf</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
```

Using ogr2ogr command:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs 'EPSG:4326' -s_srs 'EPSG:4277' -f 'KML' 84.kml SO.shp
```

I get this output:

```
Failed to reproject feature 0 (geometry probably out of source or destination SRS).
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer SO (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

Is there anything I'm doing incorrectly - to get this data to the correct projection?

Comment: try epsg:27700 for OSGB

Comment: iant - This worked, could you answer the question and I'll give you the credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you found the code [epsg:4277](http://epsg.io/4277) from but it is a representation of the OS national grid in degrees (if I'm reading the EPSG file correctly) the much more common EPSG code is [EPSG:27700](http://epsg.io/27700) which is measured in meters.